# Image Resolution not same in swf and php

Tags: actionscript, flash, resolution

In this url the image has perfect resolution  http://www.pikspeak.com/show.php?id=3&img=guitar

but when I am creating an .swf file for the same image the resolution is not that perfect. The link for the it is  http://www.pikspeak.com/fb.swf?id=3&img=guitar

Can any one let me know how I can improve resolution in the .swf file. In the swf file I am
loading the image using loader.

```
loader= new Loader();     
loader.load(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you shrink the image. You can make it look better by applying smoothing once it is loaded, by doing `Bitmap(loader.content).smoothing = true`.